# Is light an example of perpetual motion?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, perpetual-motion

If a photon doesn't meet an obstacle it keeps going, can we talk about of perpetual motion?

Comment: Sure, you can talk about it, but what purpose does it serve? Everything keeps going in a straight line unless something interacts with it, so what's your point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any free particle in a flat spacetime will carry on moving in a straight line at constant velocity forever. We would not normally describe this as perpetual motion because that description normally applies to mechanisms that purport to violate the conservation of energy.